# No attachments on contact form 7

Tags: attachments, plugin-contact-form-7

I've been using the contact form for several years now, for my current project I'm using the latest WordPress with the latest version of contact form 7, but for some reason, I'm not receiving attachments. I've tried everything on google so far but no luck. The form tag is in the correct place, the temp folder has 755 permission and WordPress debug is on, and while submitting there are no errors even it's not saving to the database either. I'm using contact form 7 to DB addon even there is no record of the attachment.
Can someone help me on this matter and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by activating the old version of the CF7 plugin. Don't know exactly what the reason but the old version seems to work.